# How to remove a nested entry from Python OrderedDict (ruamel)?

Tags: yaml, python-3.6, ruamel.yaml, ordereddict

I'm using https://github.com/wwkimball/yamlpath and the excellent [ruamel YAML parser](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/) to load and work with YAML files. I need to remove an entry from a YAML file but can't see how to obviously do that. Here's an example:

Source YAML snippet:

```
sports:
  football:
    - Dallas Cowboys
    - Miami Dolphins
    - San Francisco 49ers
```

I can get the YAML paths to these but how can I delete (say) the Miami entry?
Using ruamel.yaml gives me a data structure like this:

```
ordereddict([('sports', ordereddict([('football', ['Dallas Cowboys', 'Miami Dolphins', 'San Francisco 49ers'])]))])
```

I can access an entry by saying `data['sports']['football'][0]` but how can I remove that element from the YAML file? I see there's a "pop" option but what needs to be supplied in this example for nested keys?

I've looked at the yamlpath CLI tools and there doesn't seem to be a delete option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `'Dallas Cowboys'`, is displayed as a the first element of a list, but it
is actually a `CommentedSeq`, which is a subclass of a list that can hold comments and other information.

However, you **can** delete an element from that, just like you would from any list, using [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=del#the-del-statement)::

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
sports:
  football:
    - Dallas Cowboys
    - Miami Dolphins
    - San Francisco 49ers
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print('debug:', type(data['sports']['football']), 
                     isinstance(data['sports']['football'], list), '\n')


del data['sports']['football'][0]
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
debug: <class 'ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq'> True 

sports:
  football:
    - Miami Dolphins
    - San Francisco 49ers
```

If you only have a pop option you would need to pop element `0`, so substituting the `del` line in the above with:

```
 data['sports']['football'].pop(0)
```

gives the same result.

I hope either of those can be done with yamlpath

Comment: Thanks - I did play with the del option you quoted and that works fine, but is there a way to do that programmatically with variables? 

Something like:


a = "'sports'"
b = "'football'"
c = 0

del data[a][b][c]

Attempts using eval don't work ...

Comment: Sure, if you have already assigned them you can do `del data[a][b][c]`,